# how to add actionlisten upon dispose

Tags: java, dispose, actionlistener

i want to stop the Sound when the windows gets closed, how can i add an actionlistner upon dispose?

```
 public Tetris(boolean sound) {

    statusbarLabel = new JLabel(" 0");
    add(statusbarLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    Board board = new Board(this);
    if(sound){
        Sound.gameSound.play();
    }

    add(board);
    board.start();


    setSize(200, 400);
    setTitle("Tetris");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a `WindowListener`:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

   @Override
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
     Sound.gameSound.stop();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[java.awt.event.WindowListener.windowClosing/Closed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html)